# Finding the number of times a column has had maximum number for that particular row

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm pretty new to Python. I'm trying to define a function for the below set of data.

[demo.csv]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wJeAKlBnP3MBTlNykYBHP8D-V0X4ClpPWdJpddaetbQ/edit?usp=sharing

Assume that in the given data columns `cell 1` to `cell 6` is irrelevant. I want to know how many times `cell 7`  had a maximum value when compared to data in column `cell 8` to `cell 16` for that particular row. So the code  should ideally check for all the rows where `cell 7` has a maxvalue when compared to `cell 8` to `cell 16` and print that number.

I am working on something, but i lost myself in the middle. Here's my code:

```
def ntimes(filename):
    data=pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    cntcell7=0
    t='cell7'
    column_names = list(data.columns.values)
    max_index = data.idxmax()
    row_data = data.loc[max_index, column_names[-10:]]
    final_column_name = row_data.idxmax()
    for j in final_column_name:
        if final_column_name==t:
            cntcell7=cntcell7+1
        return (cntcell7)
ntimes("demo.csv")
```

Lemme explain what i tried to do. I tried to find the column name for every time there's a max value in  last 10 columns using `idxmax()` and iterate that over all the rows. Then count the number of times that column name appears. But, I definitely did something wrong here.

Ideally for the given set of data, the count should return as `4`

Comment: So, are you saying you want the number of times column 'cell 7' had a value that was greater than all the values in columns 'cell8' through 'cell 16' on the same row?

Comment: Yes. Thats right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest way to select a number of columns, but this works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [34224, 47465,  758,    3326,   106,    142,    363,    104,    120,    121],
    [5710,  2492,   117,    153,    100,    103,    173,    100,    103,    103],
    [38737, 18950,  271,    928,    105,    118,    348,    103,    118,    127],
    [5514,  3175,   128,    184,    100,    102,    165,    100,    102,    103],
    [115285,    97418,  743,    4570,   111,    139,    670,    111,    172,    176],
    [177423,    386661, 1312,   7201,   150,    229,    888,    134,    174,    224]
])

max_in_col0 = df[0] == df.iloc[:, range(0,10)].max(axis=1)
print(max_in_col0.value_counts()[True])
```

Of course, this also works, but I included the above since you mentioned wanting to select a specific set of columns:

```
max_in_col0 = df[0] == df.max(axis=1)
print(max_in_col0.value_counts()[True])
```

The `.iloc[:, range(0,10)]` selects columns 0 through 9, so in your data you'd probably go `.iloc[:, range(6,16)]`.

Comment: Note that the data is just the data you already had, but in a format that doesn't depend on some external source - generally something you should do in your question.